# how to call on the same thread from a different action listener

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, awt, actionlistener

I am making a GUI for a music player I have 2 buttons I want to run on the same thread but on different action listeners one is to play the music and one is to stop the music. Here is my code:

```
 ActionListener bl2 = new ActionListener() { // play button 
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             System.out.println("listener1" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
             System.out.println("beep"); //created a new thread here so that my GUI won't freeze up
             Runnable runnable = () -> {
             cl.play();
             };
             Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
             thread.start();
            }

        };
 ActionListener bl3 = new ActionListener() { //supposedly to stop the music which the other thread is running
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cl.stop();

            }
       };
```

I also have a pause button to be able to pause the music. My problem is that I don't know how to stop my music whenever I click the stop button in my GUI it executes (I had the method print out whenever its called) but won't stop the music, that's why I think that to stop my music I need to call my method in the same thread as the play button is running in, is this correct? How do I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the same method as in the running-thread, you could use a shared 'volatile' boolean in a synchronised method on the 'control'-thread.

Let's name this boolean "isPlaying";
You would then in the running-thread frequently check the value of this boolean.
And in the controller-classes you could then change the value of this boolean to false if you'd like the Runner-thread to stop playing, and then you could keep checking the value, and when it goes back to true, you could start playing again(it would require some calls between methods going round, but it's do-able).

If you'd like to save a position of where it stopped playing you could constantly inside the Runner-thread save the position in a long field, I don't think the control-thread needs access to this (unless you want to display it in a field I guess).

Short example:

```
public class Example {

    static volatile boolean isPlaying;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        //runner
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            try {
                Example.play();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("fail");
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();

        //control
        Runnable runnable2 = () -> {
            Example.stopButton();
        };
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(runnable2);
        thread2.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Example.stopButton();

    }

    public static void play() throws InterruptedException {
        isPlaying = true;
        int i = 0;

        while (isPlaying) {
            //code to play music

            System.out.println("playing - " + i);
            i++;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        System.out.println("Out of loop, stopped playing");
    }

    public static void stopButton() {
        synchronized (Example.class) {
            isPlaying = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you I am so sorry if this is a dumb question but where do I put my action listeners?

Comment: I'd put them in the class that is responsible for controlling the application (just ease of use). They don't need to be shared among threads, so volatile is not needed I guess... Always try to 'ezp synchronization to a minimum as it has an overhead cost (flushing the cpu-cache, reading straight from ram, blocking reads, etc...)